# SQL query to return ongoing auctions

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table

```
Id   AuctionName    URL     StartDate                 EndDate                  
1    auction1     image   2015-01-11 22:27:21     2015-01-12 14:25:22       
2    auction2     video   2015-01-12 05:30:50.0   2015-01-14 08:18:10
```

I get the currentTimeStamp using Java like this:

```
public Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp(){
  java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  String currentDate=dateFormater.format(date);
  Timestamp currentTimestamp=Timestamp.valueOf(currentDate);
  System.out.println(currentTimestamp);
  return currentTimestamp;
}
```

This is my output.

2015-01-12 05:30:50.0

What is the right SQLQuery to retrieve currentAuctions. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to ask here. Have a go at rewriting your question so people know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What is `currentAuctions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, AuctionName FROM auctiontable WHERE (NOW() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate);
```

You could altenatively replace NOW() with the string formed in your Java code, but this is cleaner.

Comment: If MySQL server and the host where you're running Java have the same time, then yes, otherwise, it's a no. Watch out for time zones.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question.Instead of trying to find faults ,you gave me an answer.I really appreciate the help